# How to get the SQL Server username through a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get SQL Server username through C# code ?

Comment: Which SQLserver username exactly? You can use various SQL Server functions such as `SUSER_SNAME()` for example

Comment: SQLserver username of current user which  by password logged to SSMS. TNX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `SELECT SUSER_SNAME()` against your database. Or just get it out of your orginal connection string.